# Zend Framework - Doctrine2: ManytoOne Mapping

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, doctrine

OK, if anyone can help me with this that would be great, because it appears to be intractable.

I have 2 entities set up in a new zf-boilerplate project as below. I am trying to follow the tutorial on Zendcasts.com - [One-to-Many with Doctrine 2](http://www.zendcasts.com/one-to-many-with-doctrine-2/2011/03/), but can't get doctrine to recognise the associations I have mapped. If I run `orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql`, it dumps the generated Sql, but NOT the ALTER TABLE statements at the end which should would create the Foreign Key Mapping, I can't get that to work properly.

I've tried everything I can think of, the JOIN statement I need to run obviously doesn't work either, but I figure if I can just get Doctrine to recognise the ALTER statement I can carry it from there.

Any ideas would be great, let me know if you need more info.  I thought at first maybe the .ini file might be set up wrong, but I think this is more something to do with the relationship annotation?

### Library/Photo/Entity/Gallery.php

```
<?php

namespace Photo\Entity;

/**  
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Photo\Entity\Repository\MyGallery")  
 * @Table(name="gallery")  
 */  

class Gallery {   

 /**  
 * @Id @GeneratedValue  
 * @Column(type="smallint",nullable=false)  
 * @var integer  
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="galleryID")  
 */  

 protected $id;  

 /**  
 * @Column(type="string", length=200)  
 * @var string  
 */   
 protected $gallery;
```

### Library/Photo/Entity/Photo.php

```
<?php  

namespace Photo\Entity;  

 /**  
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Photo\Entity\Repository\MyPhoto")  
 * @Table(name="photo")  
 */  

class Photo {  

 /**  
 * @Id @GeneratedValue  
 * @Column(type="smallint",nullable=false)  
 * @var integer  
 */  
 protected $id;  

  /**  
 * @Column(type="smallint",nullable=false)  
 * @var integer  
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gallery")  
 * @JoinColumns({  
 *    @JoinColumn(name="gallery_id", referencedColumnName="id")  
 * })  
 */   
 protected $galleryID;
```

Comment: As far as I can see your don't have a problem with mapping but with the mapping generator tool, which is a total crap of software. I would recommend not using it and writing the notations and db manually

Comment: thanks, but Im not generating the entities, I have already mapped them myself. I used the tool to dump the sql as a debugging exercise to see what Doctrine was reading from my entities. from this I can deduce that there is a problem with the relations. i originally tried orm:validate-schema, but the command wasnt recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... I see.. Check you column names, `gallery_id` vs `galleryID` looks suspicious.

If it is `gallery_id`, then you have to change the `$galleryID` annotation to `@Column(type="smallint", nullable=false, name="gallery_id")`

Generally, everywhere in the object model you should use the object field names, for example `mappedBy="galleryID"`, but the column itself should be mapped with the appropriate DB name, like I mentioned `@Column(name="gallery_id")`, or for example `@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="gallery_id" referencedColumnName="id")})`

Comment: yup thats done it, thanks! interestingly, this line @Column(type="smallint",nullable=false) on $galleryID seemed to prevent the foreign key being generated as well